# Showing linear independence for all $x\in ℝ$, but linear dependence when only on $\mathbb R = \{x>0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-independence

I'm having trouble with the first part of this question:

"Show that $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=|x|$ are linearly independent as functions on all of $\mathbb R$, but linearly dependent when considered as functions defined only on $\mathbb R^+ = \{x > 0\}$."

I think I have answered the linear dependence part correctly.

for $x>0$, and $a,b$ scalars $\in \mathbb R$:

$af(x) + bg(x) = 0$. $ax + b|x| = 0$.

$ax + bx = 0$ [since $x$ is positive I can drop the absolute value signs].

$(a+b)*x = 0$ since $x>0$, either $a = -b$ or $b = -a$. We have a nontrivial solution and can therefore conclude linear dependence.

I'm just having trouble proving linear independence on all of $\mathbb R$. I'm also confused as to how we go from a linearly dependent subset (i.e. $f$ and $g$ with only positive real $x$ values), to a linearly independent set in all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Striczdoeaking, you show that **if** said linear combination is 0 on the positive reals **then** $a=-b$. Incidentally, we can show the same - **if** $af+bg=0$ on all of $\Bbb R$ **then** $a=-b$ - also over all of  $\Bbb R$. What you want to do in order to show linear dependence is: exhibit $a$ and $b$ that are not both $=0$ and with $af+bg=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $af+bg=0$. Then, in particular, $af(1)+bg(1)=0$ and $af(-1)+bg(-1)=0$. In other words, $a+b=-a+b=0$. But then $a=b=0$. Therefore, $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent.

Comment: This is very helpful. So you've shown that when taking positive and negative real x values, the only possible solution is the trivial one, thus proving linear independence. I frequently find myself getting stuck trying to prove things with one equation or example. Just have to remember that showing a relation like this is just as effective. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RT Note that it's the same as how you would go about it in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  If $av + bw = 0$, then $av_i + bv_i = 0$ for *each* component $1\leq i \leq n$. Here the "components", instead of being discrete, can be all of $\mathbb{R}$.  As you point out, $af + bg = 0$ means $af(x) + bg(x) = 0$ for *each* $x$ (on the considered domain).